# Why is $V^{*}$ naturally a right vector space over a division ring $K$, where $V$ is a left vector space over $K$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $V$ be a left vector space over a division ring $K$. This simple means that $V$ is a left-unital module over the division ring $K$. My question is that why is $V^{*}$, the set of linear functionals on $V$ naturally a right vector space over $K$. Why do we need the opposite ring $K^{op}$ of $K$ to make it into a left vector space?

Comment: $K$ is a left vector space over $K$. What is the form of  an element $f$ in the dual space $K^*$?  Is it easy to see that $f$ is a right multiplication by an fixed $\lambda=f(1)$?

Answer (score 2):

Your situation is a special case of a more general construction.

If $_RM_S$ is an $R,S$ bimodule and $_RN_T$ is an $R,T$ bimodule, then $\hom(_RM, _RN)$ has a natural $S,T$ bimodule structure. The multiplication is given by $(f\cdot t)(x):=f(x)t$, and $(s\cdot f)(x):=f(xs)$ for each $f\in\hom(_RM, _RN)$.

In your situation, $R=N=T=K$, the bimodule structure of $_KK_K$ being obvious, and $M=V$ being a left $K$ module that you could consider a $K,\mathbb Z$ bimodule. (Or else you can just forget about the $S$ in the description above.)

The reason why a left module structure doesn't transfer directly to the right [has been discussed before](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1915986/29335), and there you can find an explanation of why any left $R$ module structure is the same as a right $R^{op}$ module structure.