# Let $D$ a division ring. Why $D^n$ needs to be a right $D$-vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, noncommutative-algebra, division-ring

Let $D$ be a division ring then take $M_n(D)$ the matrix ring over $D$. Now we have that $D^n$ the only simple left $M_n(D)$-module. During the proof some authors (e.g. Lam in "A first course in non-commutative algebra"), note the fact that we have to take $D^n$ as a  right $D$-vector space. I don't see why.
Any help? Thanks.

Comment: This is apparent already with $n=1$ Consider the 1x1 matrix $(a)$. This corresponds to the "linear transformation" $T:x\mapsto ax$ with $x$ ranging over $D^1=D$. But this function is $D$-linear only if $D$ acts on $D^1$ from the right! Then we have
$$T(xb)=a(xb)=(ax)b=T(x) b$$ for every $x\in D^1$, $b\in D$. If $D$ were to act from the left, and $ab\neq ba$, then we would violate linearity as $b T(x)=b(ax)=(ba)x$ but $T(bx)=a(bx)=(ab)x$.

Comment: I suspect this has been explained multiple times on the site already. [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2487971/11619).

Comment: Thanks for both comments!!