# What does "a category itself can be regarded as a sort of generalized monoid" mean?

Tags: category-theory, monoid, monoidal-categories

*Categories for the Working Mathematicians* says

> the  fundamental  notion  of category  theory  is  that  of  a
>   monoid - a set with a binary operation of multiplication that is
>   associative  and  that  has  a  unit;  a  category  itself can  be 
>   regarded  as  a  sort  of  generalized monoid. Chapters VI and VII
>   explore this notion and its generalizations.

What does "a  category  itself can  be  regarded  as  a  sort  of  generalized monoid" mean?

Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like chapters VI and VII will explain that...

Answer (score 5):

Per the passage itself, a more complete explanation will occur later in the text. That said:

The starting observation is that we can identify **monoids** with **categories with one object**. The intuitive direction is that for any category $D$ and any object $*\in Ob(D)$, the collection of morphisms $Hom(*,*)$ forms a monoid under composition. If $D$ has only a single object, this is the collection of *all* morphisms; thus, each one-object category gives us a monoid of morphisms.

The other direction may feel a bit slippery, but it's really no harder. Given a monoid $M$, we consider the one-object category $C_M$ with object $*$ and a morphism $f_m:*\rightarrow *$ for each $m\in M$, with the composition rule corresponding to multiplication in the monoid: $$f_m\circ f_n=f_{m\cdot n}.$$ Note that the object $*$ has absolutely no content - one of the themes of category theory is that it's the *morphisms*, not the objects themselves, that are actually important, and this is a great example of that.

- Incidentally, and very importantly, this correspondence also carries over to *maps*: homomorphisms between monoids correspond exactly to functors between the corresponding categories.

Now what about an arbitrary category - that is, when we have *multiple* objects? Well, each object $*$ considered on its own has an attached monoid $Hom(*,*)$, as noted above, but we have additional structure present due to the morphisms between *distinct* objects. So a one-object category is a monoid (and indeed that's an exact correspondence), but an arbitrary category is somehow **a bunch of monoids with some connections between them**.

---

Along the same lines, groups correspond to one-object categories where every morphism is invertible (with group homomorphisms corresponding to functors between those), with "generalized groups" being arbitrary categories where all morphisms are invertible - these are called *groupoids* (warning: this clashes with earlier usage of the term).

We can also view other algebraic structures like rings as one-element categories with various properties or additional structure, but [this gets more complicated](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/345004/is-it-possible-to-define-a-ring-as-a-category).

Comment: A common exercise to illustrate why equivalence of categories is preferable to isomorphism of categories is to show that the category of monoids is equivalent but not isomorphic to the category of one-object categories. The OP can work out the details once they've covered the relevant background material, namely the definition of equivalence of categories, assuming they haven't yet.